# Select multiple rows from html table and send values to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table where I need to select multiple rows and send first cell value of each row to a function. I tried the follwing code. This selects only one row and sends only one value to the function. If I select multiple rows only the first value selected is entering the function. How do I solve this issue?

**test.html**

```
<table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
            <td>1 000€</td>
            <td>1 200€</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
            <td>1 000€</td>
            <td>1 200€</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
            <td>1 000€</td>
            <td>1 200€</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" class="ok" id="tst" value="OK" onclick="" />
```

**test.js**

```
$("#table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
   var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
   alert(value);    
});

$('.ok').on('click', function(e){
   var selectedID=$("#table tr.selected td:first").html();
   fnMatchID(selectedID);

});

function fnMatchID(selectID){
//some code here
}
```

DEMO :::: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65JPw/2/)

I need to select multiple rows and send all the first cell values of the selected rows to a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to call the function multiple times or send the data along as an array, there are two things you can do.

Either way, don't removeClass on .siblings(), if you want to be able to select multiple rows. You might also consider using .toggleClass("selected") instead of .addClass("selected"), if you want to be able to unselect rows.

**Solution 1: Send data as array of strings**

```
$("#table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected');    
   var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
   alert(value);    
});

$('.ok').on('click', function(e){
   var selectedIDs = [];
   $("#table tr.selected").each(function(index, row) {
      selectedIDs.push($(row).find("td:first").html());
   });


   fnMatchID(selectedIDs);

});
```

**Solution 2: Call function repeatedly**

```
$("#table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected');    
   var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
   alert(value);    
});

$('.ok').on('click', function(e){
   $("#table tr.selected").each(function(index, row) {
      fnMatchID($(row).find("td:first").html());
   });
});
```

Either way, what you're probably looking for is the .each function:
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 4):

simple solution would be like this,

```
$("#table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('.ok').on('click', function(e){
    var selected = [];
    $("#table tr.selected").each(function(){
        selected.push($('td:first', this).html());
    });
    alert(selected);
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/65JPw/6/)